# Should I use a seperate table instead of many to many field in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I needed to assign one or more categories to a list of submissions, I initially used a table with two foreign keys to accomplish this until I realized Django has a many-to-many field, however following the documentation I haven't been able to duplicate what I did with original table.

My question is : Is there a benefit to using many-to-many field instead of manually creating a relationship table?   If better,  are there any example on submitting and retrieving many-to-many fields with Django?

Answer (score 8):

From the Django docs on [Many-to-Many relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships):

> When you're only dealing with simple many-to-many relationships such
>   as mixing and matching pizzas and toppings, a standard ManyToManyField
>   is all you need. However, sometimes you may need to associate data
>   with the relationship between two models.

**In short:** If you have a simple relationship a Many-To_Many field is better (creates and manages the extra table for you). If you need multiple extra details then create your own model with foreign keys. So it really depends on the situation.

**Update :-** Examples as requested:

From the docs:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(Person, through='Membership')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Membership(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
    date_joined = models.DateField()
    invite_reason = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

You can see through this example that membership details (`date_joined` and `invite_reason`) are kept in addition to the many-to-many relationship.

However on a simplified example from the docs:

```
class Topping(models.Model):
    ingredient = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class Pizza(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    toppings = models.ManyToManyField(Topping)
```

There seems no need for any extra data and hence no extra model.

**Update 2 :-**

An example of how to remove the relationship.

In the first example i gave you have this extra model `Membership` you just delete the relationship and its details like a normal model.

```
for membership in Membership.objects.filter(person__pk=1)
    membership.delete()
```

Viola! easy as pie.

For the second example you need to use [`.remove()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.remove) *(or `.clear()` to remove all)*:

```
apple = Toppings.objects.get(pk=4)
super_pizza = Pizza.objects.get(pk=12)

super_pizza.toppings.remove(apple)
super_pizza.save()
```

And that one is done too!

Comment: An example would help: People work on Films.  This could be a many-to-many.  But I used a through table to include "role" information: actor, director, cinematographer, etc.  Also, django's ManyToMany has a "through" operator to help the ORM create ManyToMany relationships with this extra metadata.

Comment: @Elf i was just being lazy and hoping the example in the docs would suffice. I'll add one now ;)

Comment: Example of a class is great - however my problem is adding and retrieving manytomany fields - That is the missing example in the docs.

Comment: @afshin you should add that to your Question thats a good question too.